# Why do all day events not show up in the Outlook To-Do Bar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007, calendar

When adding appointments as all day events in Outlook, for some reason they don't show up in the To-Do Bar. I don't want to have to keep switching from Mail to Calendar view each time I want to just check what I have going on tomorrow.

So, can you get all day events to display in the To-Do Bar?

Comment: I've been trying to work out why some of my events were not appearing in the calendar and some were. I came across this question and never made the connection that its because they are all day events. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't". it's a feature. See this comment by outblog in July 07

http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2007/06/21/introducing-the-to-do-bar.aspx#3652822

"We intentionally decided that the To Do bar for Outlook 2007 would work the way it does, it isn't a bug that all day events or multiple-day events don't show up, that was the design for the feature. There is no way to change this behavior in Outlook today."

A workaround maybe to create your appointments as 0 duration at 00:00 or 23:59 or whatever time find least offensive, rather than as all day appointments.

Comment: Thanks for posting that article. I find their comment "Because not everyone works in the same way, we have tried to make the To-Do Bar as flexible as possible" rather ironic as many of the comments on the blog essentially ask for more customisation. There is virtually nothing you can change about the way it displays things, just what it displays. Anyhow, thanks again for the link and the 0 duration idea seems to be better than inputing actual times.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this has been fixed in Outlook 2010 and all day events now show up in the To-Do bar.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question, but homework deadlines do have a due time - the time of the lecture when you have to hand them in, or perhaps the end of the day.

You could set the time to one of these and then the entry would show up in the to do bar.

Comment: Yeah I guess you could argue that they do have a due time. But I dont like having the times show up in the appointment as it takes up most of the space and then you cant actually see what the appointment itself is. Also, I put in the title of the appointment what period (we have 6 periods/lessons in a day) it is due in, so having a time also is unnesseccary

Answer (score 1):

You could make the homework assignments tasks instead of calendar events (which more accurately reflect what they are) and the task would show up in the To Do Bar.

If you already have many made as events, just drag them to tasks and it will create a new task from the event.

Comment: Yeah, but that would mean calendar events and homework deadlines would be in different sections. Also I like to be able to see the deadlines on a calendar, its quicker and neater to look at. It is a good idea though, im just quite OCD when it comes to things like organising.

Comment: Although, I could make each dealine a calendar event and a task, which I guess would give me the best of both worlds. I would want to find a way to automate the process of copying a calendar event to a task as its a waste of time making both an event and a task for each deadline. Maybe that is another question though.

Comment: Once you've created one just drag it to the other. For example, take an event you've created and drag it to "Tasks". It creates a task with the same subject line. In the future, I'd create the task first and then drag to calendar. It is easier to make it an all day event after that. No re-typing of info.